# Use html template in gwt

Tags: html, gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp

I want to realize a MVP gwt application using [this external HTML template](http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469).

Is it possible create HTML pages and use them in a gwt project instead of write java code in "view" classes to produce HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can get to HTML in GWT is [UiBinder](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html)

> At heart, a GWT application is a web page. And when you're laying out a web page, writing HTML and CSS is the most natural way to get the job done. The UiBinder framework allows you to do exactly that: build your apps as HTML pages with GWT widgets sprinkled throughout them.

Creating lots of HTML pages is not really what GWT is about. It uses a single HTML page and loads your GWT pages in there using JavaScript.

**If you want a Bootstrap theme**, you can use [GWTBootstrap3](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3), or [GWT-Bootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/) (still runs bootstrap 2) perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

I'd like also to mention [HTML Module](http://docs.jboss.org/errai/3.0.0.20140325-M5/errai/reference/html_single/#sid-51806600_ErraiUI-CreateanHTMLtemplate) of [JBoss Errai](http://erraiframework.org/) project as it allows to write a valid html 5 templates and wire them to GWT Java classes.
for example here's the code:

ComplaintForm.html

```
<div class="complaint">
 <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
 <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
 <textarea id="text" placeholder="How can we help?"></textarea>
 <button id="saveButton">Save</button>
</div>
```

ComplaintForm.java

```
@Templated @Page
public class ComplaintForm extends Composite {
  @Inject @Model Complaint complaint;
  @Inject @Bound @DataField TextBox name;
  @Inject @Bound @DataField TextBox email;
  @Inject @Bound @DataField TextArea text;
  @Inject @DataField Button saveButton;

  @EventHandler("saveButton")
  public void onSave(ClickEvent event) {    
    sendComplaintToServer(complaint);
  }
}
```

as you can see there's even no need of instantiating of the widgets.

and there's a lot of more stuff.